# Python read CSV adding back slashes in to data

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read in a CSV file using python that looks like this...

```
34    "Username is (\"user1\")"
762    "Username is (\"testuser\")"
24    "Username is (\"sample user\")"
```

I am using this...

```
with open('test.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:

    csvFile = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t')

    for row in csvFile:
        print(row)
```

But the output I am getting looks like this...

```
['34    "Username is (\\"user1\\")"']
['762    "Username is (\\"testuser\\")"']
['24    "Username is (\\"sample user\\")"']
```

But I want ....

```
['34    "Username is ("user1")"']
['762    "Username is ("testuser")"']
['24    "Username is ("sample user")"']
```

Where am I going wrong, do I need to specify and escape character?

Comment: What are the fields you have in each line? Are there 2 fields or just one?

Comment: [RFC4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) stipulates that literal `"` should be written as `""` (`"` two times), what did create file you are using? Quote *If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with another double quote.*

Comment: This is the format of the file that I have, I do not have any control over it. I am trying to read it in Python so I can output it in a more compliant format

Comment: Wouldn't an easy solution be to do some minimum post processing to remove incidences of ' \\" ' and replace them with just a ' " ' ?

Comment: Doing some pre-processing sounds like a solution, but I am thinking about using quotecar or escapecar when the file is read in to achieve the same thing

Comment: @Daweo That RFC is not a standard. "This memo provides information for the Internet community.  It does not specify an Internet standard of any kind."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv uses backslash `(\)` character to escape the embedded double quotes.

However, by default the default csv module uses a double quote character to escape double quote character.

You can set `escapechar` parameter in `csv.reader` function.

Something like this:

```
 csvFile = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t',  escapechar='\\')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. So I guess now it is reading them in correctly I can escape them properly before writing them out to a new CSV file